# "unary operator expected" in condition in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#even or odd

echo enter the no 
read num
i=1
while [ $i -le $num ]
do
   if [ `expr $i % 2` -eq 0 ]
   then
    "$num is even"
  else
echo "$num is odd"
fi
i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> [: ==: unary operator expected

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "following error"?

Comment: this [: ==: unary operator expected

Comment: `==` does not show up in the code you posted.

Comment: `expr` is ancient syntax, from before shells had built-in math -- something that's been guaranteed ever since the 1991 publication of POSIX.2. It's much, **much** more efficient to use `i=$(( i + 1 ))`, or `$(( i % 2 ))`.

Comment: Due to the error in the `expr` syntax (missing space after `+`), the `$i` gets set to an empty string, which causes the condition

    `[ $i -le $num ]`

to be evaluated as 

    `[ -le $num ]`

leading to the error I'm getting:

    `expr: syntax error` and `1.sh: line 10: [: -le: unary operator expected`.

Comment: After fixing the problems mentioned above, you'll be awarded with another errors (missing echo, also - is `4` really odd as the script says?)...

Comment: (btw, `==` shouldn't be used with `[` -- see the [POSIX `test` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), which only specifies `=` as a string comparison operation. Using `/bin/bash` guarantees you'll have extensions available for this particular script, but it's better not to be in the habit of using unnecessarily-noncompliant syntax).

Comment: echo -n "Enter number upto even odd series: "
read n
i=2
while [ $i -le $n ]
do
rem=$(( $i % 2 ))

if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "$i is even number"
else
  echo "$i is odd number"
fi
i=$(($i + 1))
done

Without expr it work but with it not... thanks @charles duffy

Comment: Thanks, both of you for your information

Comment: Consider also making use of http://shellcheck.net/ -- that'll catch things like missing quotes (`[ $i -le $n ]` is better written as `[ "$i" -le "$n" ]` -- `[` is able to do better error handling that way, and if the user enters `10 -o 1 = 1`, for instance, the original unquoted version will read that as `[ 1 -le 10 -o 1 = 1 ]` and return a truthy result, whereas the quoted version will correctly cause an error because you're doing a numeric comparison on a string that isn't a number).

Comment: If the shell is bash, you can also run `if (( i <= n ))` -- though that's an extension not guaranteed to be present in `/bin/sh`, so use that only in scripts with a `#!/bin/bash` (or ksh, or other extended shell) in the shebang.